# Visual Studio 2022 - Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-2022

When I debug Blazor application in Visual Studio 2022 I got this error:

> Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information may be
> available in the output window.
>
> Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a
> virus or potentially unwanted software

The error does not appear when I debug MVC project.

[image]

Comment: It seems like your computer has an antivirus installed. Uninstall it and try again.

Comment: @Alejandro I closed the antivirus, nothing has changed

Comment: Completely uninstall it (or at least disable it), not just close. It's seems it's blocking the compiled executables from running with a false positive.

Comment: @Alejandro, great thank you :) I will accept your answer if you write it in the answers section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiled executable is being blocked by an antivirus and therefore Windows cannot run or debug it.

The ideal solution would be to completely uninstall the antivirus causing the trouble, and your program will run unmolested. You can also temporarily disable it to test before changing anything.

If you really want to keep an antivirus installed and be able to develop at the same time, you can add an exception to it to let run your program (typically the whole project folder will do, but the compiled executable is the bare minimum you need to exclude from analysis).

Comment: "... The ideal solution would be to completely uninstall the antivirus causing the trouble, and your program will run unmolested."
Really? That is what you see as "The ideal solution"? "completely uninstall the antivirus"?
Wow.

Comment: Yes, that's the best I can think of. This problem is just an example of the problems antiviruses cause to usabiity, not to mention the serious damage they do to security (despite what they claim). It's 2024, antiviruses should not even exist at this point.

Comment: Usability is only relevant in a world that has a minimum of security. And 2024 is not a magic number when we talk about security. Maybe you should try to learn about all the innumerable ways that a machine can be and is attacked everyday. And just because those dangers are hidden from the common user, that doesn't mean that they don't exist.
But no matter. To me your words are irresponsible and even dangerous to uninformed people. We two are obviously living in two very different worlds and have not much to say to each other.

Answer (score -1):

What solved for me was ...
I installed the GSL VCPKG in visual Studio - and it turns out that its build scripts replace the normal build scripts, but they have an error that casues this message.

FIX:

- uninstall GSL VCPACKAGE
- set the project properties options:

  - Configuration Properties/vcpkg/use Vcpkg: no,
  - Use VCPkg Manifest: no
  - Install VCPKG dependencies: no.

It may be a sledge hammer approach - but it had wasted a lot of my time.
To look a little deepr: the first of my issues ocurs in the VS2022 build -
whenever I REBUILD  I get this error, BUT when I BUILD afterwards it links FINE, and the target is built.
The issue was with the GSL VCPKG that I installed in VS2022.
Apparently it hijacks the build process scripts and replaces them with its own - and it is their rebuild script that is causing the issue
I hope this helps someone! The build line include the gsl script path - the giveaway, although it took me a week to spot this... Unistalling the VCpkg and turning off all the VCPkg option in VS2022 build options solved it.

What a WASTE of TIME GSL! (I instlalled GSL to try to get rid of the horrible code hints - in C++ about should check for nullness - using gsl ... BAH! HUMBUG again MS! C++ has relly lost it - it is no longer coherent. Some the template error meesage are HUGE and frankly diffcult to interpret).
Var Args are discouraged becaue the compiler cant handle the type safety - yet C# can. C++ is now a viable alternative to sticking pins in your eyes. Sad day.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To ensure uninterrupted execution of your Go applications without interference from the Antivirus application, consider adding the Go build path from where the main.exe is executed to the Exceptions list.

Alternatively, if you prefer to exempt all Go apps from being scanned for potential threats by the Antivirus, include the following path in the Antivirus Exemptions.

C:\Users\Your-User-Name\AppData\Local\Temp\

Comment: The "alternative solution" of adding "C:\Users\Your-User-Name\AppData\Local\Temp\" to the exceptions is a very dangerous idea. One is basically undermining our own defenses and the antivirus power. Please do not follow such "advice".